# Making a div as display block on page load

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a div visible when the page loads, initially it's invisible

Here is what i am trying to do,in css i am setting the display to none, but when the page loads i am trying make the div visible using the class, but the div is still hidden.How can i show the div using class.

```
 <div id='list' class='listclass'></div>
```

css:

```
 #list
 {
   display: none;
 }
```

in document ready:

```
$('.listclass').css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: Have you tried `$('.listclass').show();`?

Comment: show us your full script..

Comment: Your div has no content so you don't see it even if it is visible? :P Try this. this is working http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/V3A28/

`$(function () { $('.listclass').css('display', 'block'); });`

Comment: The script works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dCGud/). Make sure you're importing the jQuery library, and using the script after the DOM is ready. Also, there is no content in the `<div>` - maybe its showing and you just can't _see_ it?

Comment: As Vucko points out in their JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CyWdC/, there is nothing wrong with your code, so long as a) it occurs in document load and b) you have content in the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code works correctly in fiddle : [See](http://jsfiddle.net/2ynQF/3/)**

You can try

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('div.listclass').css('display', 'block');
 });
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2ynQF/1/)

OR

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#list').css('display', 'block');
 });
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2ynQF/2/)

Comment: Assuming their code *is* in the document load, these are no different to the original code (which also actually works).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Yes, you are right. OP code works correctly (*mentioned in answer)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.listclass').show();
});
```

It could be that you're using jQuery in noConflict mode so the example above will resolve that.

Are there any errors showing in your console? Also can you confirm you're not mistaking the div showing with no content (therefore nothing visible even though it's there) with the div actually being hidden?

Comment: Are you sure? Surely element styling takes precedence over ID styling anyway?

Comment: This is not correct. jQuery applies the CSS via the `style` property of the DOM node. This [beats almost everything](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity). That the jQuery selector uses a class has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You're all correct. I wasn't thinking about this properly. Modifying my answer

Comment: Assuming the SO is correct in applying their code *in document load*, their original code is not faulty: From Vucko http://jsfiddle.net/CyWdC/

Answer (score 0):

Make a jQuery file with in it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.listclass').fadeIn();
});
```

The standard `display` property of a div is already `block` so you dont have to give that when you fade it in.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your way is that you're applying the JS before the DOM is ready.

If you put your code within `$(document).ready(function(){ //CODE HERE });` it should work.

### EDIT:

Apologies, I missed the section where it said that it was already in document.ready.
Are you sure there are no other JS errors which would be preventing any further execution of JS?

Answer (score 0):

can u try use the id(list) not the class(listclass) inside your jquery to set the display to block because u used the id to set it to display=none

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('#list').css('display','block');
});
```

same as @Ishan Jain 2nd example

Comment: That is incorrect (and makes no difference to the original) as `element styling` takes precedence over all styling rules. (including id selectors). The same element is being selected by `$('#list')` and `$('.listclass')`